# How to store and display a variable value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some fields on my view screen and when user clicks on modify button, its redirected to next screen where he can edit those contents.

Everything is working fine except my one field which is drop-down.

I am comparing the values coming from 1st screen and basis on that I am again hard coding my drop-down values but I want to make it more generalize.

In the code given where I have used

```
<xsl:when test="search = 'Guides'">
     <option value="G" selected="true" >Guides</option>
</xsl:when>
```

I want to make it more generalized and instead of guides in both places, I want it to catch that value coming from 1st screen in a variable and use that value.

This is the x-path from where my value is coming

`//faml/response/quicklinkresponsedto/quicklink/quicklinkdto/quicklink/search`

`XSL`

```
<select id="fldsearch" name="search" class="objselect">
                                    <xsl:choose >
                                        <xsl:when test="search = 'Guides'">
                                                <option value="G"  selected="true" >Guides</option>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <option value="G">Guides</option>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:choose >
                                        <xsl:when test="search = 'Latest Offers'">
                                                <option value="L"  selected="true">Latest Offers</option>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <option value="L" >Latest Offers</option>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:choose >
                                        <xsl:when test="search = 'Templates'">
                                                <option value="T"  selected="true" >Templates</option>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <option value="T" >Templates</option>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:choose >
                                        <xsl:when test="search = 'Videos'">
                                                <option value="V"  selected="true" >Videos</option>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <option value="V" >Videos</option>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    </select>
```

Comment: This sounds like an excellent use case for Saxon-JS, which allows you to program the response to user events like clicking a button from within the client-side XSLT stylesheet code.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you provide me an answer for the same. Thanks.

Comment: I could if had a spare day or two to work on it, and a more complete requirements statement...